# Python mathematical operators sequence

Tags: python, math

```
a=0
b=5
```

And when we try to get result of this:

```
print str((23-11)/a*b)
```

We get the divide by zero error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>   
>       print str((23-11)/a*b) ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
>   But if we change positions:

```
print str((23-11)/b*a)
```

The result is zero:

> 0

Should we get always divide y zero error (because (b*a) is zero)?

Comment: What you're describing is [*"precedence"*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) - `x/b*a` is evaluated as `(x/b)*a`, not `x/(b*a)`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe that's rather associativity.

Comment: @bereal good point, they have the same precedence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`((23-11)/a*b)` becomes

[image]

`((23-11)/b*a)` becomes

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In `print str((23-11)/a*b)` this is what happens

1.Calculate 23-11

2.Divide step by a(0)

3.Multiply step 2 by b(5)

It is step 2 which gives the zero division error

However in `print str((23-11)/b*a)` this is what happens

1.Calculate 23-11

2.Divide step 2 by 5

3.Multiply step 3 by 0.

There is no ZeroDivisonError because the computer divides by 5 then multiplies by 0, not divides by 0*5. This is because in order of operations Multiplication and Division are of equal priority so they are just executed left to right.

Answer (score 2):

The evaluation of `(23-11)/a*b` is decomposed as follow: ((23 - 11) / a) * b

See: [Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

Answer (score 1):

It's giving you a zero rather than an error because it's dividing by the first variable and multiplying by the second.
Like, if you change it to ((23-11)/(b*a)) or((23-11)/(a*b)) it will return the divide by 0 error, too. But at the moment it's calculating (23-11)/5 * 0, I think.